# After long wait time bluetooth socket state mixed ups

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm currently trying to fix a problem I encountered with my Android app which require a Bluetooth connection. For a moment everything seem to work right, But i noticed something strange when the slave Bluetooth device, I want to connect with, is not powered on. Here is my code :

```
private void connectDevice() {
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "Socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }


    //Try to establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "Unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    //Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
    mActionBar.setSubtitle("Connected");

    return;
    }
```

And here is where I call this method :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_enabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setupCom();
            break;
        }
        else {
            // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
            if(D)   Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            break;
        }
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            retrieveAddresse(data);
            connectDevice();
        }
        break;
    }
    return;
}
```

My problem is that, when I'm not in range or the device I want to connect to is not powered on, the connectDevice() method seem to execute all the code even if it's not possible to connect because Android OS don't want to be blocked by the connection process. I noticed this problem because mActionBar.setSubtitle("Connected"); get executed and because when I try to reconnect when I'm in range or the slave bluetooth module is ON. I can't connect to it unless I relaunch my application.

Comment: How do you get the device address? Using bluetooth discovery?

Comment: The address is retrieved by a DeviceListActivity class that give me all the devices in a list I select one device and I extract the address this part work.

Comment: Right you are correct about the thread. But why do I get a connected state if it's impossible that I'm connected ?

Comment: Your code can be blocked at btSocket.connect(), but independent of your device can or can't connect, after that line, your code will not be blocked anymore. Maybe your connectedThread can block, but it runnig outside the main thread. Do you get some error when you try to connect with a device outside the range?

Comment: Yes as stated in the explanation of my problem everything works fine but I have problem when the device is outside the range. If this happen I have to re-launch the app or I will not be able to connect. The state of the connection seem fuzzy to the apps and I'm not able to disconnect or connect even if the bluetooth device is now in range.

Comment: Are you saying even when a device was not in the range, no one exceptions occurs on btSocket.connect()? Have you tried to put these lines `mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket); mConnectedThread.start();mActionBar.setSubtitle("Connecté");` inside the first try? In this way they will be executed only if the devices establish a connection.  As actually they are outside try/catch, they will always executed, even without connection.

Comment: That was the problem Mr. Mateus ! What a stupid mistake. Know I have to check if the bluetooth device got disconnect that the state change but this will need some tweeking !

I would have liked to promote your post but I can't do it because it's a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these lines :

```
mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
mConnectedThread.start();
mActionBar.setSubtitle("Connecté");
```

inside the first try. In this way they will be executed only if the devices establish a connection. As actually they are outside try/catch, they will always executed, even without connection.